# spring security authentication from database. "No session found for current thread" in the browser.

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying a simple spring security authentication from the database. But I am getting the  "No session found for current thread" in the browser when I try to login. there are no errors in the console.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<name>DoctorAssist</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Oracle database Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.efsavage.twitter.bootstrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>

  <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>

 <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>
                    true
                </showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
 </project>
```

servelet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                                   
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp" />
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">

</global-method-security>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login />
    <logout />
    <remember-me />


    <session-management invalid-session-url="/loginfailed.jsp">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>

</http>

<!-- hibernate DAO for authentication with sessionFactory dependency from dispatcher-
servlet.xml defined in the web.xml -->
<beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.mycompany.daoimpl.UserLoginDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory">  
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.mycompany.service.UserLoginService">
    <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean> 

<authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha" />
     </authentication-provider>      
</authentication-manager>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url"   
   value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/globaldatabse" />
    <property name="username" value="docassist" />
    <property name="password" value="Thinkpad" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="myDataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop   
    key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


</beans>
```

DAO class

```
 public class UserLoginDAOImpl implements UserLoginDAO {


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Users loadUserByName(String name) {
    if (name != null && !name.equals("")) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Users> usr = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("from Users where username=?")
                    .setParameter(0, name)
                    .list();

        if (usr.size() == 1) {
            return usr.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

LoginService class

```
public class UserLoginService implements UserDetailsService {


private UserLoginDAO userDao;

public void setUserDAO(UserLoginDAO u) {
    userDao = u;
}

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    if (username != null && !username.equals("")) {
        Users user = userDao.loadUserByName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }

        GrantedAuthority grantedAuth = new UserGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        CustomUser cu = new CustomUser(user.getId(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                                       new GrantedAuthority[]{ grantedAuth });
        return cu;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

UserGrantedAuthority.java

```
    public class UserGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3786297951121082647L;

private String authority = null;


public UserGrantedAuthority(String auth) {
    authority = auth;
}

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

}
```

CustomUser.java

```
public class CustomUser implements Serializable, UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1201392234549297485L;
private long id;
private String password;
private String username;
private GrantedAuthority[] authorities = null;

public CustomUser(int id, String username, String password, GrantedAuthority[]  
    authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> auth = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (int i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
        auth.add(authorities[i]);
    }
    return auth;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}


@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a crucial part in your database configuration. You have no transaction manager nor any transaction specification configured. As such no session will (or can) be opened by Spring.

You might want to read [the transaction chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) from the Spring Reference Guide. That explains how to setup transactions.

Judging from your code you should have a `<tx:annotation-driven /> element` next to a HibernateTransactionManager..

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: That didn't change the error. I think it is something to do with the spring-security configuration. I am relatively new to spring.. searched google extensively.. but not able to find the problem.